# How to derive $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x^3-1}dx=\frac19\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I am interested in the integral$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x^3-1}dx=\frac19\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)$$

I thought about approaching this by expanding $\sin(\pi x)$ into its taylor series:
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x^3-1}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2n+1}}{x^3 -1}dx$$

However I'm not sure where to continue from here. I also considered the general integral $$I(a)=\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(ax)}{x^3-1}dx$$ however Wolfram Alpha says that the general case is divergent so I am not sure that is the right approach. If anyone can help me with this integral I would be very grateful.

EDIT: The result given by Wolfram Alpha is wrong and as such I can wager to say that this integral probably does not have a closed form. Feel free to prove me wrong though.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the term $\frac 1{x^3-1}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}$?

Comment: Yeah the series for sine won't work

Comment: @MarkViola I have but I am left with a very ugly expression involving a sum of incomplete gamma functions.

Comment: How did you obtain that result? Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: @Zacky WA gives the result but every other CAS puts the integral at $−0.924004640359...$ which is very different from the WA result. The decimal expansion seems to be accurate however, because the integrand is purely negative on $[0,1)$... Very strange indeed

Comment: @zacky You're correct.  That can't be the correct answer.  The LHS is negative and the RHS is positive.

Comment: @Zacky I used Wolphram but apparently its wrong?

Comment: Yes the result given seems to be wrong.. I also believe that when we combine a trig function with a polynomial and the bounds aren't $\infty$ we don't get a nice result. Using partial fractions and relying  on the sine integral  might work, but it won't be nice.

Comment: @Zacky Agreed, I was excited because I thought that this integral had surprisingly simple closed form, but WA has let me down.

Comment: The right side is about $0.8475...$